# What is the Erlang way to do stream manipulations?

Tags: stream, erlang

Suppose I wanted to do something like:

```
dict
  .values()
  .map(fun scrub/1)
  .flatMap(fun split/1)
  .groupBy(fun keyFun/1, fun count/1)
  .to_dict()
```

What is the most elegant way to achieve this in Erlang?

Comment: Oddly enough that is a construct I very seldom have need of in my real code. I would probably do it one map operation over the dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct easy way of doing that. All attempts I saw looked even worse than straightforward composition. If you will look at majority of open source project in Erlang, you will find that they use generic composition. Re-using your example:

```
to_dict(
groupBy(fun keyFun/1, fun count/1, 
flatMap(fun split/1, 
map(fun scrub/1, 
values(dict))))).
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity though :(

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a construct that's natural in Erlang. If you have a couple functions, regular composition is what I'd use:

```
lists:flatten(lists:map(fun (A) ->
                            do_stuff(A)
                        end,
                        generate_list())).
```

For a longer series of operations, intermediary variables:

```
Dict = #{hello => world, ...},
Values = maps:values(Dict),
ScrubbedValues = lists:map(fun scrub/1, Values),
SplitValues = lists:flatten(lists:map(fun split/1, ScrubbedValues)),
GroupedValues = basil_lists:group_by(fun keyFun/1, fun count/1, SplitValues),
Dict2 = maps:from_list(GroupedValues).
```

That's how it'd look if you wanted all of those operations grouped in one shot together.

However, I'd more likely write this in a different way:

```
-spec remap_values(map()) -> map().
remap_values(Map) ->
    map_values(maps:values(Map)).

-spec map_values(list()) -> map().
map_values(Values) ->
    map_values(Values, [], []).

-spec map_values(list(), list(), list()) -> map().
map_values([], OutList, OutGroup) ->
    %% Base case: transform into a map
    Grouped = lists:zip(OutGroup, OutList),
    lists:foldl(fun ({Group, Element}, Acc = #{Group := Existing}) ->
                        Acc#{Group => [Element | Existing]};
                    ({Group, Element}, Acc) ->
                        Acc#{Group => [Element]}
                end,
                #{},
                Grouped;
map_values([First|Rest], OutList, OutGroup) ->
    %% Recursive case: categorize process the first element and categorize the result
    Processed = split(scrub(First)),
    Categories = lists:map(fun categorize/1, Processed),
    map_values(Rest, OutList ++ Processed, OutGroup ++ Categories).
```

The actual correct implementation depends a lot on how the code's going to be run -- what I've written here is pretty simple, but might not perform well on large amounts of data. If you're actually looking to process an endless stream of data you'll need to write that yourself (though you may find Gen Servers to be a very useful framework for doing so).